# Symfony4 / Doctrine, how select 'distinct' objects ? getResult() return an array of string, not an array of object

Tags: symfony, doctrine, symfony4

From Symfony4/Doctrine, I need to select all "distinct" objects with a entity's repository custom method, below a simple example :

An minimal example table of an entity :

[image]

A simple `$em->getRepository(MyEntity::class)->findAll();` return all data of my table in object structure.

I'm looking for a way to do the same query with a distinct in relation with the column name. With my example, this query must return the objects 1, 3 and 5.

I tried this entity's repository custom method :

```
public function getDistinct(){
    $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('myentity');
    $res = $query
        ->select("myentity.name")
        ->distinct(true)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
    return $res;
}
```

But the `$res` var contains an array of string results, not a array of object (I want an array of entity Objects).

How can I do that ?

Comment: Not sure if that's the only mistake but you have to select at least the id to hydrate entities

Comment: hmmm how can I select id and name, but only distinct on name :?

Comment: what about `group by myentity.name` instead of `distinct` ?

Comment: groupBy does the job ! Its a strangely approach I find, but it works ^^ I have a list of object without any duplicate object with same names

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `group by myentity.name` instead of `distinct`.

```
$res = $query
   ->select("myentity")
   ->groupBy("myentity.name")
   ->getQuery()
   ->getResult();
```

This should do the job as expected.

Comment: It's extremely bad practice to use 'group by' and it can throw an error "GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by"